# Regex Pattern to ignore the inner parenthesis in the input string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have been struggling to find the solution for below requirement

Input string  is **Sum(Spec("any text1" : "any text2"),spec("any text3" : "any text4"))**
I want to match the string  **spec("any text1" : "any text2")** and **spec("any text3" : "any text4"))**

pattern  which I tried is `Spec\(([^)]*)\)`
[image]

This pattern works for above input , but if any of the **any text1** ,**any text2**, **any text3** and  **any text4** contains parenthesis then it fails to match

ex input  **Sum(Spec("any text1 with (bracket)" : "any text2"),spec("any text3" : "any text4"))**

[image]

It is also possible that text can contain the quotation marks as well `"chassis \"4\""`.

Comment: `\bSpec\((?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\)`

Comment: If you can have stray `(` or `)` inside `"..."`, you will need a more specific solution though. But we'll need more details, like if it is possible to have ``\"`` in between `"..."`.

Comment: Does that work for you?

Comment: yes it is possible that text can contain the quotation marks as well ```"chassis \"4\""```

Comment: I understand "yes" as "there can be brackets in between `"..."`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(?is)\bSpec\((?>"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^()]|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbSpec%5c%28%28%3f%3e%22%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c%5c.%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*%29*%22%7c%5b%5e%28%29%5d%7c%28%3f%3cc%3e%29%5c%28%7c%28%3f%3c-c%3e%29%5c%29%29*%28%3f%28c%29%28%3f!%29%29%5c%29&i=Sum%28Spec%28%22any+text1%22+%3a+%22any+text2%22%29%2cspec%28%22any+text3%22+%3a+%22any+text4%22%29%29%0d%0aSum%28Spec%28%22any+%28text1+with+%28%5c%22bracket%5c%22%29%22+%3a+%22any+text2%22%29%2cspec%28%22any+text3%22+%3a+%22any+text4%22%29%29%0d%0a&o=is).

*Details*:

- `(?is)` - case insensitive modifier
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `Spec\(` - `Spec(` text
- `(?>` - start of an atomic group:

  - `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` - a `"..."` string that may contain escaped `"` chars
  - `|` - or
  - `[^()]` - any one char other than `(` and `)`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<c>)\(` - `(` char is matched and an empty value is pushed on to Group `c` stack
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<-c>)\)` - `)` char is matched and an empty value is popped off the Group `c` stack
- `)*` - end of the atomic group, repeat zero or more times
- `(?(c)(?!))` - a conditional construct: if Group `c` stack is not empty fail, trigger backtracking
- `\)` - a `)` char.